Jest does not recognize es6 imports on Umijs Max Project using Pro antd
I m trying to create tests in my react aplication built with ReactJs and @umijs/max CLI (https://umijs.org/docs/max/introduce).
I use the same umi cli to generate Jest files but when i run the tests it displays this error:
 Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /home/mypcname/projects/myprojectname/src/app.tsx:84
            unAccessible: <_403_1.default />,
                          ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
      2 | // This file is generated by Umi automatically
      3 | // DO NOT CHANGE IT MANUALLY!
    > 4 | import * as Plugin_0 from '/home/mypcname/projects/myprojectname/src/app.tsx';
        | ^
      5 | import * as Plugin_1 from '@@/core/helmet.ts';

      6 | import * as Plugin_2 from '/home/mypcname/projects/
    > 4 | import * as Plugin_0 from '/home/mypcname/projects/myprojectname/src/.umi-test/plugin-access/runtime.tsx';

      7 | import * as Plugin_3 from '/home/mypcname/projects/
    > 4 | import * as Plugin_0 from '/home/mypcname/projects/myprojectname/src/.umi-test/plugin-antd/runtime.tsx';

The problem is that i tested lots of possible causes like: adding babel, config ts-jest, add type module to package json, modify tsconfig.json jsx field and its not solving my problem. Honestly i don't know what is causing this error.
My files config file is set like this:
Jest config:
import { Config, configUmiAlias, createConfig } from '@umijs/max/test';

export default async () => {
  try{
    return (await configUmiAlias({
      ...createConfig({
        target: 'browser',
        jsTransformer: 'esbuild',
        jsTransformerOpts: { jsx: 'automatic' },
      }),
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        '<rootDir>/jest-setup.ts'
      ],
      collectCoverageFrom: [
        'src/**/*.{ts,js,tsx,jsx}',
        '!src/.umi/**',
        '!src/.umi-test/**',
        '!src/.umi-production/**'
      ],
      transform: {
        '\\.(ts|tsx)$': ['ts-jest', {
          esModuleInterop: true,
          isolatedModules: true,
         }],
        '\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
        '\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$': 'jest-transform-stub'
      },
      moduleFileExtensions: [
        'js',
        'jsx',
        'ts',
        'tsx',
        'json',
        'node',
      ],
    })) as Config.InitialOptions;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw e;
  }
};

Tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "@@/*": [
        "./src/.umi/*"
      ],
      "@@test/*": [
        "./src/.umi-test/*"
      ]
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.d.ts",
    "./**/*.ts",
    "./**/*.tsx"
  ],
  
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", 
  ]
}

Babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}

If you want to test just create a project with umimax cli and generate the jest setup with umi cli (https://umijs.org/en-US/docs/guides/test) and try to test if a page is rendering. In my enviroment it always triggers that error.
OBS:
OS Details: Ubuntu 22
